# unknown syscall.SysProcAttr field 'Unshareflags'

Tags: linux, go, system-calls

I was trying out the Syscall in Go and had created the struct

```
cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{
        //New UTS              Child become 1          Mount Name Space
        Cloneflags:   syscall.CLONE_NEWUTS | syscall.CLONE_NEWPID | syscall.CLONE_NEWNS,
        Unshareflags: syscall.CLONE_NEWNS, //Dont share the container to the host,
    }
```

but I get the error :

```
unknown syscall.SysProcAttr field 'Unshareflags' in struct literal
```

From the documentation I understand it does not work in a mac. I tried running it on an Ubuntu VM:

> Linux xxx 4.2.0-27-generic #32~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 15:32:26
>   UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Doesn't work as a sudo user either.

Comment: it works with `GOOS=linux` on macOS, go version: `1.12.5`.  what's your go version?

Comment: As mentioned above, I am running it within an Ubuntu system 14.04.1-Ubuntu..Go version: go version go1.2.1 linux/amd64

Comment: Have you tried update to a later version of Go?

Comment: Go1.2 was release in 2013. Update to the current version of go.

Comment: This field [was added in Go 1.7](https://golang.org/doc/go1.7#syscall).